# why does my maven tests fails when run as a whole and passes when ran individually?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, mockito, junit4, powermockito

Hi I am having a strange scenario.
I have a spring boot java project . I have lots of Junit tests as well.

when i run the tests from the terminal by issuing the command mvn clean test, 2 tests belong to a class fails

however if run the those tests belonging to that class from the eclipse Run as >> Junit tests it passes .

any idea why does this happens ? and how can i fix it ?

the following is my sure fire plugin configuration

```
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.18.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Force alphabetical order to have a reproducible build -->
                    <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

thank you

Comment: Could you insert relevant `pom.xml` sections? Eg. Surefire config if your project or the project's parent has any.

Comment: Does the execution stop if you place a breakpoint into the test and run as Debug JUnit test with Eclipse?

Comment: yes it hits the break point if i debug as junit test from eclipse . thank you

Comment: There are many explanations for that. Per example, some test are changing a class that other test also use, and when the tests run in a different order (Eclipse and maven build not follow the same execution order), some of them break. The best way to know what is happenning is posting the unit test code and the error.

Comment: Check if Eclipse and Surefire run your tests with the same version of Junit! (https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html)

Comment: Can we take a look at the stack trace for your failed test cases?

Comment: https://github.com/prasanthmp500/unitest-issue.git  here i am setting up my project . could you do a git clone and perform a mvn clean test . it might take around 10 minutes to run the complete test suit . two tests from NotificationResourceIntTest will fails . however from eclipse if you run it will pass .thank you a million